# Using command blocks to set players on fire

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use a command block to set a player (which already has permanent fire resistance) permanently on fire, mostly as an aesthetic. Right now I have the following command:

```
/data merge entity <Playername> {Fire:100}
```

When I run it it says "Unable to modify player data". How do I get this to work? I'm new to commands in Minecraft.

Comment: You can't put `<` and `>` in posts, the system interprets that as HTML. You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 2):

This approach could work:

```
/execute at @p run summon minecraft:small_fireball ~ ~3 ~ {direction:[0.0,-10.0,0.0]}
```

It targets a player and constantly summons a small fireball from a [Fire Charge](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fire_Charge) around them, which would set the player on fire. You could potentially modify this a bit to create a permanent "on fire" effect.

([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/bl7g38/set_player_on_fire_with_data_merge_entity/))